# Noise reduction from audio

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to remove noise from audio in blender vse. I am new to blender and I want to use it for video editing.
Can anyone please suggest some way to reduce noise from sound in vse

Comment: Blender's Video Sequence Editor is very simple for audio. i will Recommend you Audacity for that, it's free and Open Source

Comment: Blender is a poor choice for editing video, but is even a worse choice for editing audio. Use a dedicated audio editing app.

Comment: Can you seggest me some video editor

Comment: Resolve, openshot, shotcut, HitFilm Express, avid media composer first, premiere, vegas, final cut pro. As for audio use audacity.

Comment: If you really want to edit audio professionally at a good price, I recommend the products from https://acondigital.com/products/ ...these guys know how to write solid software. (No, I don't have anything to do with them, but I work with it myself) ...forget Audacity, that thing is a bug (but free).